# Multiple editors on single page wordpress

Tags: wordpress, tinymce, sections

After lot of research i got the answer for achieving multiple editors on single page in WordPress that it can be done using tinymce.But i am confused where exactly i need to implement the coding part of tinymce in my custom theme

Thank You

Comment: Hi, Megha, welcome to StackOverflow! It'll help if you can make your question very specific and provide more context in the description.

An example of a question that may receive quicker help could be: "How do I use tinymce in my wordpress custom theme to achieve multiple editors on a single page?" and then share a snippet of what you've tried so far that's failed and any errors you see for that failure.

Comment: You can also use ACF plugins to achieve the same

Comment: Thank you for your reply, i am new to WordPress i want to have multiple editors on wordpress admin page so that i can separate images and text content in my front end pages

Comment: Thank you Balwant for your reply. But i need to achieve this task without using plugins

Answer (score 1):

Just add [wp_editor](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_editor) function in your custom theme files.

Here is example:

```
wp_editor( $post_content, $custom_id, $settings = array() );
```